# How to run custom code in JDB session?

Tags: java, debugging, jdb

In an IDE like IntelliJ I can stop the execution at a breakpoint and then execute arbitrary code using the snippet view.

Can I do the same when using commandline debugger JDB attached to a process?

I suspect that under the surface IntelliJ uses some functionality exposed by JVM to allow arbitrary code execution. So it should be present in the command line debugger as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "eval" command to do that:

for class Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] arg) {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 3;
        System.out.println("a+b=" + (a+b));
    }
}
```

you can evaluate the code inside jdb following way (make sure to compile with -g: javac -g Main.java)

```
VM Started: Set deferred breakpoint Main.main

Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", Main.main(), line=5 bci=0
5           int a = 1;

main[1] step
>
Step completed: "thread=main", Main.main(), line=6 bci=2
6           int b = 3;
main[1] eval a+1
 a+1 = 2
main[1] eval java.lang.System.out.println("Hello: " + a);
Hello: 1
 java.lang.System.out.println("Hello: " + a); = <void value>
```

Comment: how does jdb eval multiple line code？like for-loop

Comment: I have no idea :) I am pretty sure this place is the best place to start your research: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/man/jdb.html

Comment: I posted new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72581943/how-does-java-jdb-eval-multiple-line-code